# Allowing only registered users to use contact form

Tags: php

How can I allow only registered users in my site to use the contact form?
Non-registered users won't be able to use it,as the contact form would contain
input type where registered usernames or emails can be entered.
Thank you.

Comment: [How are we supposed to answer your question without knowing what your code looks like?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: youd be better off hiding the form completely from anyone thats not authenticated

Comment: `if(condition){ do something }else{ do something else }`

Answer (score 1):

When a user has signed in, you usually set a session

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;
```

On the contact page you can do

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    // Code to redirect to another page, because you're not signed in!
}
```